# Android, i want to create loading dialog that will show percentage while the code is executing

Tags: android, progress-bar, loading

I have a algorithm that need about 4-5 sec to get all the contacts from sim and bind them in my autocompletetextview (which happens in onCreate) so while that happens how can i create a dialog that will show like loaing and percentage or a progress bar... pls some reference or help:D

Comment: Here's a link for you: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to used the ProgressDialog:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html

It can show a indeterminate progress bar or a percentage. To update the percentage bar, you'd possibly need to use the class AsyncTask.
I put a link which shows the two classes working together:
http://sites.google.com/site/androidhowto/how-to-1/asynctasks-with-progressdialogs

I'm adding a more useful link:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/162201/Painless-AsyncTask-and-ProgressDialog-Usage

Answer (score 0):

You should write the part updating the progressbar as an `AsyncTask` to see the loading lively. You can also use `Handler`s.

this can help:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask, it has helpful methods namely

```
      protected void onPreExecute(){
        //Show a dialog here
     }
      protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
```

You can publish your percentage progress in `onProgressUpdate` method and in `onPostExcecute` dismiss the dialog